# Advanced TS Types: Wrapper type that mirrors keys but becomes new value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a type definition that takes some interface, like this:

```ts
interface IMyInterface {
   name: string
   subobject: {
     boolField: boolean
   }
}
```

And then have `OptionsTransformer` wrap it and, for each `key-value` pair, keep the key the same but change the value to a new class `FieldOptions<type>`. For example:

```ts
const transformed: OptionsTransformer<IMyInterface> = {
     name: new FieldOptions<string>(),
     subobject: {
         boolField: new FieldOptions<boolean>()
     }
}
```

This is because I know that `TS` interfaces disappear at runtime, so you can't really check against them during runtime. I want to be able to write a function like the following (my real-life use case is input in the body of a post request: I know what it should look like, and want to verify that it looks like that):

```ts
const runtimeVerifier<T> = (
   options: OptionsTransformer<T>, input: Record<string, unknown>
) => {
   //for each value in input, run the it's verifier. If it's a sub-object,
   //recurse and do runtime verifier on the sub-object.
}
```

Another requirement is that at compile time, If I add a field to `IMyInterface`, I want there the `TS` compiler to give me an error like "Your optionsTransformer is missing the field .".

I got pretty far with this definition:

```ts
//this class doesn't matter, but here for completeness
class FieldOption<T> {}

export interface IValidBody {
    [x: string]: boolean | string | number | IValidBody 
}

export type OptionsTransformer<T extends IValidBody> = {
    [key in keyof T]-?: T[key] extends IValidBody 
        ? IOptionsForFields<T[key]> 
        : FieldOption<T[key]>
}
```

But I'm getting some pretty complex errors on the sub-objects and am having trouble deciphering them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is `OptionsTransformer ` and `FieldOption`?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi sorry, had the `OptionsTransformer` interface named the wrong thing in the "What I had tried section." I renamed it in an edit. FieldOption doesn't matter, but I added it too for clarity.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer since it sidesteps your actual question, but you might want to consider an existing object validation library like [joi](https://joi.dev/) or [ajv](https://ajv.js.org/). Both are fully TypeScript-aware.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple days of hacking, I found the solution.

I was very close - having the generic in `OptionsTransformer` forced the recursive subtype to also implement the interface - and even if it did, the type got erased (for a reason I know not) and then it *didn't* implement the type.

The solution was to have `OptionsTransformer` generic not extend a subtype.

The final solution looks like this, with classes renamed for clarity:

```ts
//can be any class!
class AnyClass<T> {
    constructor(item: T) {
        console.log(typeof item)
    }
}

//just using string here, but can be any type(s).
interface RecursiveInterface {
    [key: string]: string | RecursiveInterface
}

//fix is here: T no longer extends Recursive interface. 
//I'm not 100% sure why, but it works. Any sub object will be 
//"duck typed" into recursive interface, so you can nest as deeply
//as you desire. 
type RecursiveInterfaceWrappedWithClass<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends RecursiveInterface ? RecursiveInterfaceWrappedWithClass<T[key]> : AnyClass<T[key]>
}


//example: interface with nested object. Only go 1 deep in this example,
//but you can nest as far as you'd like.
interface MyObject {
    foo: string
    bar: {
        baz: string
    }
}


//here's the wrapper.
const myObjectWrapped: RecursiveInterfaceWrappedWithClass<MyObject> = {
    foo: new AnyClass('string'),
    bar: {
        baz: new AnyClass('hi')
    }
}
```